# Высокое потребление ЦП скриптом на jQuery (не баг ли Bootstrap это?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap

Загрузка процессора скриптом на `jQuery` высока и составляет ~15%. Браузер `Google Chrome`.

```
var pbar = '<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" style="width: 100%;">На %PATH% свободно %FREE%Гб из %TOTAL%Гб</div>';
$('#core_status_ajax').html(pbar);
```

Боюсь, проблема в бутстрапе, поэтому вот фрагмент верстки.

```
<div class="section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="progress progress-striped" id="core_status_ajax">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Полные исходники на [гитхабе](https://github.com/mironoff111/PartCCTV/blob/master/client/webgui.phtml)

Comment: А вы попробуйте выполнить все по отдельности и посмотреть что будет

Comment: @jas Только Core и Cam Log Modals - нагрузка 0%

Comment: @jas Core Settings Modal тоже не нагружает.
Только верхние два (Progress Bar и Cam List - те самые ~15%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблемы была вовсе не в скрипте, а в прогресс-баре: нагрузка от анимации.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте кэшировать все запросы, добавьте параметр `cache: true`

Comment: Неа, ничего не поменялось..

Comment: Тогда по шагам дебаж через https://developer.chrome.com/devtools и находит в чем корень проблемы.

Comment: Всё гораздо хуже. 
`var pbar = '<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" style="width: 100%;">На %PATH% свободно %FREE%Гб из %TOTAL%Гб</div>';
$('#core_status_ajax').html(pbar);`
Даже это вызывает загрузку. Проблема еще глубже: в Bootstrap